# Display a custom message on wordpress upolad media window?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, backbone.js

[image]I want to display a message on WordPress media upload window.

I tried this snippet, but this one also not working. Actually I thought if this snippet will work, I will change it as per my requirements.

```php
<?php
/**
  * Plugin Name: Add new option in link to select field
  * Plugin URI: http://example.com/link-to-select-field
  * Description: This is example plugin for add new option in link to select field in wordpress.
  * Version: 1.0
  * Author: Pavan Yogi
  * Author URI: http://example.com/pavan-yogi
  * Liscence: GPL2
  */
// Reference: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173852/best-approach-when-modifying-the-media-manager/178065#178065
add_action('print_media_templates', function(){

  // define your backbone template;
  // the "tmpl-" prefix is required,
  // and your input field should have a data-setting attribute
  // matching the shortcode name
  ?>
 <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-my-custom-gallery-setting">
   <label class="setting">
   <span><?php _e('My setting'); ?></span>
   <select data-setting="my_custom_attr">
     <option value="foo"> Foo </option>
     <option value="bar"> Bar </option>
     <option value="default_val"> Default Value </option>
    </select>
  </label>
</script>

 <script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  // add your shortcode attribute and its default value to the
  // gallery settings list; $.extend should work as well...
  _.extend(wp.media.gallery.defaults, {
    my_custom_attr: 'default_val'
  });

  // merge default gallery settings template with yours
  wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
    template: function(view){
      return wp.media.template('gallery-settings')(view)
           + wp.media.template('my-custom-gallery-setting')(view);
    }
  });

});

  </script>
  <?php

}); ?>
```

The HTML is appearing with source code but does not append any option to  LINK TO drop-down select button. I expect the newly added options to be appear to the dropdown.